Time dilation question
I understand that an object moving at high velocity relative to an observer will appear to have time move slower. But what if the high velocity object was traveling in a circle and able to communicate with the "stationary" observer? Since the communication travels at the speed of light, wouldn't that be almost instantaneous communication with in two different inertial time frames? Would the high velocity person actually be speaking slower to the "stationary" observer?!

Traveling in a circle (even at constant velocity) means the traveler is accelerating. Not that this is a major problem, but it conflicts with your statement about "two... inertial... frames."

Thanks I'll check out Doppler Effect. Why does circular travel have to be accelerating?

@JH In the absence of acceleration an object will move in a straight line, so to get circular motion there must be acceleration.

thank you appreciate it

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#Acceleration

yes, it will be speaking slower

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632229/123208

So if Bob is "stationary" and Alice zooms past him in a spaceship at some big fraction of $c$, both Bob and Alice will think that the other person is "moving in slow motion" relative to them. This is a second-order effect that comes from the first-order effect of relativity, compounded over and over and over as one of them accelerates "up to speed."
You would think "okay but can't they just call each other up and get a definitive answer, Bob is the one talking slower and Alice is talking faster?" and the answer is no, because the inherent communication delays make it impossible to decide who is really moving in slow motion. This described motion is relative, and special relativity does not say one of these frames is correct and the other is wrong—it says that they are both right! Alice is correct that Bob is moving in slow-motion in her reference frame, Bob is correct that Alice is moving in slow-motion in his reference frame.
You are now proposing that Alice begin accelerating so that she can describe a circle about Bob, doesn't that absorb the communication delays? And the answer is, "it doesn't completely, but it does do something more interesting that speaks to the core of what relativity is predicting." When you change the situation in this way, Bob still thinks that Alice is moving in "slow-motion" for the exact same reason as before, but Alice now thinks that Bob is "sped-up". Something has changed because Alice is non-inertial!
What changed? Well, remember that time dilation is a second-order effect caused by something else? Here's a description of that something else:

Whenever you accelerate in some direction $\hat x$ with acceleration $a$, you see (after correcting for any expected Doppler shifts and signal propagations etc.) that clocks ahead of you by coordinate $x$ in that direction, tick at a rate of $1+\frac{ax}{c^2}$ seconds per second. (This also extends to the negative case; clocks appear to stop at coordinate $x=-c^2/a.$) This causes people to disagree about what is simultaneous in their reference frames, and is called the relativity of simultaneity.

When Alice starts accelerating towards Bob with an acceleration that he'd describe as $${\mathrm dv\over\mathrm dt} = {v^2\over R}$$ I believe it's a bit hard with her curved motion to specify the exact acceleration and direction that she believes she's accelerating relative to Bob, but she's definitely accelerating towards him and thus his clock is ticking faster, and that's a first-order effect rather than a second-order one, it's stronger in principle. (Mental note for me to work it out some time and see if I can derive that she sees Bob's clocks ticking $\gamma$ times faster than her own.)


Since the communication travels at the speed of light, wouldn't that be almost instantaneous communication with in two different inertial time frames?

Time dilation is not about communication delays. Time dilation is an effect that remains after correcting for any communication delays.

Would the high velocity person actually be speaking slower to the "stationary" observer?!

Yes, but again the communication aspect is incidental to time dilation. All physical processes of the moving person go slowly relative to the inertial lab frame. They breathe slower, their heart beats slower, they think slower, and they age slower. They speak slower also.
This experiment has been done with muons in a circular particle accelerator. They live pretty simple lives, they only decay and send a signal when they decay. They are experimentally confirmed to do so more slowly when traveling in a circle at high speeds.

Thanks everyone! You've given me a lot to chew on as a curious lay person.
